# UIScrollview Autolayout example with dynamic height UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I' ve been struggling for days with this issue in XCode. A working example from someone would be greatly appreciated.

I have a view controller with the following hierarchy and I am using storyboards:

View

- ScrollView

  -- View

  --- ImageView

  --- Label

  --- Label

  --- WebView

The data to the above labels, image and webview is being dynamicaly loaded from a web service. Thus the height of the elements may vary, depending on the data.

I cannot achieve layout appearance when the device is being rotated. Looks like the constraints are not valid or something is missing.

I' ve set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints of ScrollView to 0, as well as to the View inside it. For the ImageView, Labels and WebView constraints are also set between them. XCode wants to set height and width sizes explictly for the View which shows up as warning. If I set 320 and 568 it works OK for portrait but not for landscape orientation.

What's the better way to set constraints for that?

I believe that would be a common scenario for many people, building applications related to dyhamic web data. Unfortunately, I can't find the combination! Maybe Apple should simplify such cases (in Android layout is MAGIC).

Note that Webview scrolling is disabled so to have a full scroll for the View and items inside it.

If somebody has Xcode project example I would appreciate.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/jrturton/JRTWebViewWithSupplementaryViews it allows you to set header and footer views on a UIWebView, which will then all scroll as a unit

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm looking about. What I'm asking is using the native UIScrollView and UIWebView with the appropriate constraints.